# не выполняется if

Tags: python, sql

есть простецкий код который берет дату с базы данных и делает количество дней, а потом убирает либо day либо days и заменяет на дня, дней, день

```py
def repldate(user_id):
    try:
        date = datetime.strptime(worker_date(user_id), '%Y-%m-%d')
        date = str(date - datetime.now()).split(',')
        date = date[0]
        date = date.replace('-', '')

        if ('days' in date):
            date = date.replace(' days', '')
        elif ('day' in date):
            date = date.replace(' day', '')



        if date[-1] == 1:
            date = date + ' день'
        elif date[-1] == 2 or date[-1] == 3 or date[-1] == 4:
            date = date + ' дня'
        elif date[-1] == 5 or date[-1] == 6 or date[-1] == 7 or date[-1] == 8 or date[-1] == 9 or date[-1] == 0:
            date = date + ' дней'

        return date
    except:
        pass
```

при выводе

```
print(repldate(юзер из базы данных))
```

то выводится только число без дней дня день

если добовлять скобки к if и убирать нечего не происходит

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: код берет из базы данных дату к примеру 2023-01-06, а потом вычесляет сколько от сегодняшнего дня до этой даты дней. Позже код убирает day или days. Потом код если код оканчивается на 1 то будет 1 день если же на 2 то будет 2 дня если 5 то 5 дней если 0 то 0 дней

Comment: @playMaster, добавьте это, а также фактический и ожидаемый вывод в вопрос

Comment: что добавить это?

Comment: @playMaster, ваш ответ духу сообщества

Comment: когда делаю со скобками выводиться только число а без скобок также просто число выводится

Comment: @VladimirChistov, если добовляю и убираю в if скобки то просто выводится число без день дней дня

Comment: `date[-1]` это строка, `1` это число, вы пытаетесь их сравнивать — результат сравнения всегда будет ложный, строка никогда не бывает равна числу, это разные типы данных